# Dimension of $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces $H^m(X, \mathbb{Q})$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, homology-cohomology

Assume that you can't compute the cohomology group $H^m(X, \mathbb{Q})$ for$$X = \{(x : y : z : w) \in P^3(\mathbb{C}): xy = zw\}$$but you know Weil conjecture. By using Weil conjecture, give the dimension of the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces $H^m(X, \mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: This seems like a strange game, but ok... Step 1: there is an alternate description of $X$ that makes it very clear how many points $X$ has over any finite field. Do you know this alternate description?

Answer (score 3):

We have that $X$ is a smooth projective algebraic variety and $X$ is also good reduction. Therefore, we can apply the Weil conjectures and have that$$\text{dim}_\mathbb{Q} H^m(X, \mathbb{Q}) = \deg(P_mn)),$$where$$Z(X/\mathbb{F}_q, n) = {{P_1(n)P_3(n) \dots}\over{P_0(n)P_2(n)\dots}}$$with$$P_m(n) = \prod_{j=1}^{b_m} (1 - \alpha_{mj}n),\text{ }|\alpha_{mj}| = |q|^{{mj}\over2}.$$Thus, for $X$ given in the original post, we have that the only nontrivial polynomials are$$P_0(n) = 1-n,\text{ }P_2(n) = (1 - qn)^2,\text{ }P_4(n) = 1 - q^2n.$$Therefore, by the Weil conjectures, we have that$$\dim_\mathbb{Q} H^m(X, \mathbb{Q}) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }m = 0,\,4 \\ 2 & \text{if }m =2  \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Hence,$$H^m(X, \mathbb{Q}) = \begin{cases} \mathbb{Q} & \text{if }m = 0,\,4 \\ \mathbb{Q}^2 & \text{if }m =2  \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$